# How to add label in one direction on cross-sections?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, cross-section

I would like to add cross-section labels in one direction to the mouth of the river. Unfortunately, in some places label turns 180 degrees as pictured. Do you know some automatic way to solve this problem? I tried to use the advanced label settings (label manager) but it failed.

[XS LABEL http://zibimobile.pl/adik/xs_label.jpg](http://zibimobile.pl/adik/xs_label.jpg)

Comment: what version of ArcGIS are you using and do you have access to the Maplex labeling engine?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.1 and I have access to the Maplex labeling engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn on "Maplex Labeling Engine" from the Labeling toolbar. Then go into the label placement properties you will see the following option:

"Label Position" tab -> "Orientation..." button -> "Align label to direction of line" check box.

[image: Settings]

[image: Result]